# Calling PostgreSQL function with JasperReports parameters

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, jasper-reports

I created a  PostgreSQL Function

```
icalldetailsByAN(hNametext,start_date timestamp,end_date timestamp))
```

While Trying to bind my JasperReports report by updating the dataset & query editor in *Jaspersoft Studio*

```
select * from icalldetailsByAN($P{hName},$P{startDate},$P{endDate})
```

I am not getting the result

The *hName, startDate, endDate* are the parameter I have created in the report which will be the input parameter to the function `icalldetailsByAN`

When I execute the function **icalldetailsByAN** from PostgreSQL with the input I get proper result not sure what exactly mistake I am making.

Comment: Did you try the same query with const values? With JasperReports of course

Comment: You should call your function as `SELECT icalldetailsByAN($P{hName},$P{startDate},$P{endDate})`

Comment: Hi AlexThanks for your input yes when I do sent the constant value I get the result in the reports but while passing the parameter I am not getting the result

Comment: hi @viki888, Thanks for the input ...making a call SELECT icalldetailsByAN($P{hName},$P{startDate},$P{endDate}) did not help to solve my problem.

Comment: @AashishMukherjee How have you executed your function in postgresql? provide some sample data.

Comment: Hi @viki888 I have fired
 select * from icalldetailsByAN('ABC001','2016-11-07 6:35:50.924','2016-11-07 17:35:50.924')  and this is returning me result as well but when I pass select * from icalldetailsByAN($P{hName},$P{startDate},$P{endDate}) in jasper there is no output

Comment: Did you dump (check) the parameters values? Looks like a magic in case you passing the right values

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who want to print jasper report using Postgresql function. Jasper reports doesn't support PostgreSQL's refcursor like Oracle REF_CURSOR. The alternative is to change your function to return table instead of cursor. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_sql_function (
    p_param_1 VARCHAR,
    p_param_2 VARCHAR,
    ...,
    p_param_n VARCHAR
) RETURNS TABLE (
    col_1 VARCHAR,
    col_2 VARCHAR,
    ...,
    col_n VARCHAR
)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT 
                     col_1,
                     col_2,
                     ...,
                     col_n,
                  FROM 
                     your_table
                  WHERE col_a=p_param_1
                    AND col_b=p_param_2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Then in your Jasper report template just select like normal query

```
<queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                your_sql_function(
                    $P{param_1},
                    $P{param_2},
                    ...,
                    $P{param_n}
                )
        ]]>
    </queryString>
```